# When called directly, mejs_media_shortcode outputs two players

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mediaelement.js

I'm calling MediaElement.js plugin's mejs_media_shortcode PHP function ([here](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/tags/2.9.1/mediaelement-js-wp.php)) from another file, and it is writing out the normal HTML5 AND the Flash player. Others on the page work fine. Is there something that I'm missing to remove the unneeded player?

Comment: show us your code. After viewing that we can help you.

Comment: Search for "<object" in this file, it is always included on shortcode: https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/tags/2.9.1/mediaelement-js-wp.php